# Node js Multiples sessions - process

Tags: node.js, session

i create a mean stack app. When I was nearly finished, I realized that the data in memory on the server side is shared by all users.

For example, let's say when the user clicks a button, a variable is added on the server side. If another user enter in the application and click on the same button, I'd like an isolated count was conducted, but the same variable is added.

For example, if I implement a button which when clicked adds 1 to the memory variable in server side, if another user to enter the system at the same time, the same variable is added instead of creating a separate process for that user. That said, my question is: How to implement session between users, so data in memory is not share between users.

Comment: This sounds more like the need to create a user table in your database, and have variables associated with each user.  Or perhaps using local storage or sessions storage to locally persist user data. Not the need to have multiple instances of your node app running.

Comment: no, i already have tables with some datas but in manipulation of this datas the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Use node passportjs to manage user sessions in nodejs
http://passportjs.org/

Comment: i already using passport to control user login, but the internal execution works with 1 data area.